# Launching objects using RigidBody.AddForce is not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made this little function to "explode" a tunnel I've created by launching all the tiles into the air.  The problem is that it does nothing when called.  There is a rigidbody component attached to each Tile object, and the position is not being set in Update anywhere else.  Do I need another component or setting to be able to apply Impulse forces?

```
    public void ExplodeTunnel()
    {
        foreach (GameObject tile in tiles)
        {
            Rigidbody rb = tile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rb.AddForce(tile.transform.up * 200, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are these rigidbody components marked as `Kinematic`?

Comment: What is the mass of your object? is 200 enough force to launch it?

Comment: They are not Kinematic (although I did try setting them to Kinematic and saw no results) and the mass is set to 1

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

I think you need to use FixedUpdate with the physics engine not Update.

Comment: You are correct that FixedUpdate is ideal for physics and I should be using that.  I just gave it a try and that wasn't the issue though

Comment: so nothing in this looks like it shouldn't work. The thing that bothers me is we are exploding a tunnel and "tiles" are all shooting off it i am guessing in random directions. This seems to me like they are all attached to each other some how. So they wouldn't be able to independently move separately. So this may not be the correct way to make an object explode. I would narrow this down to a single object and try it. If that works you may have to work for a different method.

Comment: The tiles are children of holders that contain multiple tiles, but shouldn't the children be able to move independently of each other and the parent?

Comment: Are you sure this method gets called? and your for is executed?

Comment: Yes I put a Debug.Log in so I know it's being called correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rb.AddExplosionForce. It does a different behavior from AddForce but it gives you a more realistic explosion behavior.